# gulp: translations (gettext) only takes last .po file

Tags: gettext, gulp, po

I'm using gulp and gettext, all works well except when I have multiple .po files.

```
gulp.task('translations', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/po/*.po')
        .pipe($.gettext.compile())
        .pipe($.rename('translations.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
    });
```

I have three .po files: `lang1.po`, `lang2.po` and `lang3.po`, and I only get `lang3.po` in `translations.js`. I guess this task is overwriting things. Any suggestions how I can cat everything together into `translations.js` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is:

- step 1: compile lang1.po, compile lang2.po, compile lang3.po
- step 2: rename lang1.po to translations.js, rename lang2.po to translations.js, rename lang3.po to translations.js

Get the idea?

You probably want to `concat` instead (using [gulp-concat](https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat)).

```
gulp.task('translations', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/po/*.po')
    .pipe($.gettext.compile())
    .pipe(concat('translations.js')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
```

Hope that helps.